# Mobile browser cuts off bottom of content but works in desktop browser

Tags: html, css

Bottom keeps getting cut of in mobile view but perfectly fine in browser even when it's resized. I thought maybe the media queries aren't being addressed but they look fine. I've tried moving `.square` up by putting `top:-55%;` but it will only move in desktop browser. It doesn't move in mobile for some reason.

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">

     /* Iphone */

     @media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .project_miniwrap {
            min-width: 90%;
            top: 33%;
        }
        #tu {
            margin-top: 117px;
            margin-left: 235px
        }
        #dar {
            margin-top: 17px;
            margin-left: 25px
        }
        .square {
            color: #0D0D0D;
            font-family: 'NimbusSansNo5TOT-Medium';
            font-size: 38px;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: -15%;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 295px;
            height: 160px
        }
        .l1,
        .l2,
        .l3,
        .l4 {
            position: absolute;
            background: transparent;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #0D0D0D
        }
        .l1 {
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 8px
        }
        .l2 {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 8px
        }
        .l3 {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 8px
        }
        .l4 {
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 8px
        }
        .description {
            width: 90%
        }
        .snippet {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 45px;
            margin-bottom: 10%;
            font-size: 36px
        }
        .main_description {
            display: block;
            width: 100%
        }
        #anchor-point {
            bottom: 90%;
            position: absolute
        }
        .anchor-point {
            bottom: 90%;
            position: absolute
        }
        #container {
            top: 30%
        }
    }
    @media (max-height: 479px) {
        #tu {
            margin-top: 117px;
            margin-left: 235px
        }
        #dar {
            margin-top: 17px;
            margin-left: 25px
        }
        .square {
            color: #0D0D0D;
            font-family: 'NimbusSansNo5TOT-Medium';
            font-size: 38px;
            letter-spacing: -1px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            position: absolute;
            top: -15%;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 295px;
            height: 160px
        }
        .l1,
        .l2,
        .l3,
        .l4 {
            position: absolute;
            background: transparent;
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #0D0D0D
        }
        .l1 {
            left: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 8px
        }
        .l2 {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            height: 8px
        }
        .l3 {
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 8px
        }
        .l4 {
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            height: 8px
        }
    }
```

Site: http://imdarrien.com/

[image: Chrome app iphone]
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's being cut off because the viewport height is not large enough. Since you position `.project_miniwrap` using `top:35%;`, it's always going to position it at 35% from the top of the parent, not in the center.

Try using this to center the the div instead:

```
.project_miniwrap {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

This is the more compatible version of the above that you can use if you know the width and height, otherwise you will need to center it using JavaScript.

```
.project_miniwrap {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-right: -150px;
}
```

Comment: `.project_miniwrap` shouldn't affect the splash location though. Also I'm still not sure why the `.square` media query changes `.square` in desktop browser but not on mobile.

Comment: You might want to try adding width to the viewport as well since you're designing the page to scale across many device screens `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I was following this guide. http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972 They said not to use that width command. Should I just put it in anyways?

Comment: Because of browser compatibility perhaps? If you know the width and height of the box you can use `margin-left:-(half width); margin-top:-(half height);`, that's the older more compatible method which should be supported in all browsers.